# Mixing Full Database Encryption with Column Encryption

Tags: database, encryption, amazon-rds

If you are fully encrypting your database with AES-256, is there any reason to also encrypt individual columns? Other than performance, is there a reason not to?

The reason I'm asking is because we are currently encrypting specific columns but not the database, and are preparing to move to a full database encryption model. It would be much easier to keep the columns encrypted, as we wouldn't have to change any code. If there is a compelling reason other than my personal laziness, I could definitely use it to bolster my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best reason I can think of to encrypt the columns as well as the whole database would be for more than one level of access.  The people with the database key could see the database schema and the unencrypted columns but not the content of the encrypted ones.  Might be useful, for example, if you had a database of hospital patients with medical history.  More staff might need to know who the patient is, their next of kin, their billing info than need to know the specifics of their condition(s).  Even if the law does not require strict access to medical information in your area, the hospital policy might.

Performance is the only reason I can think of against encrypting columns in general.  Well that and the limitation it puts on them, that the encrypted columns cannot be used for keys, or at least cannot be used that way without adding a lot of complexity to the system.